# excel has problems opening a file created with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Please, if you are not able to provide a constructive solution, do not mark it as duplicate, because I have not found any solution and it says very little about your interest in providing some help.

Excel rejects the formula, but the other strings in other cells are allowed. I'm using the names of the formulas in English and have tried commas and semicolons with the same result.
The formula consists of a markdown template and has several nested conditions.
Part of the code is:

```
wb = Workbook()
sheet= wb.active
l=str(sheet.max_row+1)
formula='=CONCATENATE("**"&{}&"**"&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"- **Ponente:** "&{}&CHAR(10)&"- **Fuente:** "&{};IF(EXACT({};"");"";CHAR(10)&"- **ID:** "&{});CHAR(10)&"- **Web:** "&{}&CHAR(10)&"- **Idioma:** "&{}&CHAR(10)&"- **Etiquetas:** "&{};IF(EXACT({};"");;CHAR(10)&"- **Fecha:** "&{});IF(EXACT({};"");;CHAR(10)&"- **Notas:** "&{}))'.format("A"+l,"B"+l,"C"+l,"D"+l,"D"+l,"E"+l,"H"+l,"G"+l,"F"+l,"F"+l,"I"+l,"I"+l)
print (formula)
data={
    "Título":[titulo], 
    "Autor":[profesor],
    "Fuente":[plataforma],
    "ID":[id],
    "Web":[url],
    "Fecha":[fecha_esp],
    "Etiquetas":[etiquetas],
    "Idioma":[idioma],
    "Notas":[notas],
    "Plantilla":[formula]
}
dataframe_pandas = pd.DataFrame(data)
for x in dataframe_to_rows(dataframe_pandas, index=False, header=False):
    sheet.append(x)
wb.save(filename)
```

The console output shows the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("**"&A2&"**"&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"- **Ponente:** "&B2&CHAR(10)&"- **Fuente:** "&C2;IF(EXACT(D2;"");"";CHAR(10)&"- **ID:** "&D2);CHAR(10)&"- **Web:** "&E2&CHAR(10)&"- **Idioma:** "&H2&CHAR(10)&"- **Etiquetas:** "&G2;IF(EXACT(F2;"");;CHAR(10)&"- **Fecha:** "&F2);IF(EXACT(I2;"");;CHAR(10)&"- **Notas:** "&I2))
```

This formula is rejected by Excel, but if I copy and paste it in the excel field, I have no problem.

- Recover workbook: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OL7T.png
- Plantilla field rejected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztcpx.png
- Paste formula in field and run: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whlOA.png

So, what is the problem?

**Update**

Previously this issue was published, but it was marked as duplicated without even trying to help. Now, I am very grateful to the three people who responded.

The problem was the formula in python. I replaced all semicolons, but I must have had some typo that I corrected later and never tried again. But with the evidence provided I tried once more and it worked

Comment: With such a huge formulat it's *very* easy to end up with a typo. What does this formula do? You're generating the Excel file through code, so why have such a formula at all? Why not calculate the output in code and add it as an extra column?

Comment: Besides, the output is something that can't be used in Excel in the first place, either for calculations or printing output. Why is Excel used at all? If you wanted to create a multiline report, you should use cells in different rows and either merge them or format them to appear the way you want.

Comment: When I copied and pasted the formula into Excel, Excel rejected it.

Comment: @DavidGaertner, are you copying the formula well? I have provided screenshots that show that the formula works

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have that option too and it works without problems, but sometimes I need to edit the file manually, so I need to insert a method, ie a formula, to generate the corresponding markdown code. And no, it is not a report, it is an excel that I use as an inventory. It's not very big and I need to share it with several people with basic computer skills

Comment: Such users expect the data to appear in separate rows, not a single cell with newlines. Besides, business users are often *better* at using Excel than developers. They could tell you eg how to use VLOOKUP to lookup values from lists in other sheets. Using different rows for each calculated value will result in a cleaner UI and *far* simpler formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your `semicolons` with `,` in the formula and check.

I tried manually in libreoffice and compared it with auto generated formula. Both differs in `,` as it automatically changed `;` to `,`. Then I replaced `;` with `,` in the python file. and the auto generated excel is fine.

[image]

Comment: Do you understand what happened though? In locales where `,` is the decimal separator, something else has to be the list separator. That's typically `;`. Both separators are defined in the user's locale preferences

Comment: This was tried and failed anyway `have tried commas and semicolons with the same result.`

Comment: Amazing, it works. I guess I had several typos in the formula and it didn't work when I changed semicolons for commas. Thanks a lot, I went crazy for a couple of days, but after reading you I decided to try again and with great joy

Answer (score 0):

You can try with ExcelWriter

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
# write dataframe to excel
df_marks.to_excel(writer)
# save the excel
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Changing the library won't fix a broken formula

Comment: I will try it at the next opportunity. Thank you very much